# Whitespace in custom args on Android instrument test run

Tags: android, adb, android-instrumentation, activity-manager

I have this instrumented test suite in Android, that I would like to pass some custom arguments to. I've been using this format, as stated in the official documentation:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e key value -e class com.testpackage.tests.TestClass#testMethod
```

Where for each custom argument there needs to be a `-e key value` pair.

This works well for arguments that are numbers or strings with no whitespace in it. However, when I try to pass an argument with whitespace in it, between quotes, double quotes or not, such as `-e user_name "John Doe"`, it's not parsed correctly and I get the following error:

```
Error: No instrumentation found for: Doe
```

Which suggests the command is parsing `user_name` as `John` and trying to use `Doe` as the target test class or something.

Now, is this a limitation on this command? Or a bug? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: `adb shell ...` commands are shell commands within a shell command. So I would recommend to encapsulate the whole `am instrument ..` call again in quotes/single quotes to make sure the quote are not resolved already in the outer shell call.

Comment: that's exactly the issue. thank you! please post as an answer :D